# Extracting multiple substrings that come after certain characters in a string using stringi in R

Tags: r, regex, string

I have a large dataframe in R that has a column that looks like this where each sentence is a row

```
data <- data.frame(
   datalist = c("anarchism is a wiki/political_philosophy that advocates wiki/self-governance societies based on voluntary institutions",
   "these are often described as wiki/stateless_society although several authors have defined them more specifically as institutions based on non- wiki/hierarchy or wiki/free_association_(communism_and_anarchism)",
   "anarchism holds the wiki/state_(polity) to be undesirable unnecessary and harmful",
   "while wiki/anti-statism is central anarchism specifically entails opposing authority or hierarchical organisation in the conduct of all human relations"),
   stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

I want to extract all the words that come after "wiki/" and put them in another column

So for the first row it should come out with "political_philosophy self-governance" 
The second row should look like "hierarchy free_association_(communism_and_anarchism)"
The third row should be "state_(polity)"
And the fourth row should be "anti-statism"

I definitely want to use stringi because it's a huge dataframe. Thanks in advance for any help.

I've tried

```
stri_extract_all_fixed(data$datalist, "wiki")[[1]]
```

but that just extracts the word wiki

Comment: I think you wanted to write *a huge **library***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
> trimws(gsub("wiki/(\\S+)|(?:(?!wiki/\\S).)+", " \\1", data$datalist, perl=TRUE))
[1] "political_philosophy  self-governance" 
[2] "stateless_society  hierarchy  free_association_(communism_and_anarchism)"
[3] "state_(polity)"                                                           
[4] "anti-statism"
```

See the [online R code demo](https://ideone.com/RVOHJF).

**Details**

- `wiki/(\\S+)` - matches `wiki/` and captures 1+ non-whitespace chars into Group 1
- `|` - or
- `(?:(?!wiki/\\S).)+` - a tempered greedy token that matches any char, other than a line break char, 1+ occurrences, that does not start a `wiki/`+a non-whitespace char sequence.

If you need to get rid of redundant whitespace inside the result you may use another call to `gsub`:

```
> gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$|\\s+(\\s)", "\\1", gsub("wiki/(\\S+)|(?:(?!wiki/\\S).)+", " \\1", data$datalist, perl=TRUE))
[1] "political_philosophy self-governance"                                   
[2] "stateless_society hierarchy free_association_(communism_and_anarchism)"
[3] "state_(polity)"                                                         
[4] "anti-statism"
```

Comment: is this faster than stringi?

Comment: @Kayla I did not test. This is not the speediest solution, but it can be enhanced if the tempered greedy token is unrolled as `[^w]*(?:w(?!iki/\\S)[^w]*)*`, but it will then match empty strings. Try comparing performance with `trimws(stri_replace_all_regex(data$datalist, regex("wiki/(\\S+)|(?:(?!wiki/\\S).)+"), " $1"))` if you want to use `stringi` by all means.

Comment: I just checked and I think it's faster than stringi. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a regex. By using `stri_match_` instead of `stri_extract_` we can use parentheses to make matching groups that let us extract only part of the regex match. In the result below, you can see that each row of `df` gives a list item containing a data frame with the whole match in the first column and each matching group in the following columns:

```
match <- stri_match_all_regex(df$datalist, "wiki/([\\w-()]*)")
match

[[1]]
     [,1]                        [,2]                  
[1,] "wiki/political_philosophy" "political_philosophy"
[2,] "wiki/self-governance"      "self-governance"     

[[2]]
     [,1]                                              [,2]                                        
[1,] "wiki/stateless_society"                          "stateless_society"                         
[2,] "wiki/hierarchy"                                  "hierarchy"                                 
[3,] "wiki/free_association_(communism_and_anarchism)" "free_association_(communism_and_anarchism)"

[[3]]
     [,1]                  [,2]            
[1,] "wiki/state_(polity)" "state_(polity)"

[[4]]
     [,1]                [,2]          
[1,] "wiki/anti-statism" "anti-statism"
```

You can then use apply functions to make the data into any form you want:

```
match <- stri_match_all_regex(df$datalist, "wiki/([\\w-()]*)")
sapply(match, function(x) paste(x[,2], collapse = " "))

[1] "political_philosophy self-governance"                                  
[2] "stateless_society hierarchy free_association_(communism_and_anarchism)"
[3] "state_(polity)"                                                        
[4] "anti-statism"
```

Comment: I basically want it to look like how Wiktor Stribiżew did it. Is there a way to do that using stringi? Because he used trimws and I believe stringi is faster although I could be wrong.

Comment: Regex is more robust and easier to troubleshoot, in my opinion. Once you've extracted the matches, you can shape the data into any format you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a lookbehind in the regex.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringi)

text <- c("anarchism is a wiki/political_philosophy that advocates wiki/self-governance societies based on voluntary institutions",
 "these are often described as wiki/stateless_society although several authors have defined them more specifically as institutions based on non- wiki/hierarchy or wiki/free_association_(communism_and_anarchism)",
 "anarchism holds the wiki/state_(polity) to be undesirable unnecessary and harmful",                                                                                                                               
 "while wiki/anti-statism is central anarchism specifically entails opposing authority or hierarchical organisation in the conduct of all human relations")

df <- data.frame(text, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df %>% 
  mutate(words = stri_extract_all(text, regex = "(?<=wiki\\/)\\S+"))
```

Comment: You could simplify the regex to `(?<=wiki\\/)\\S+`, since the defining feature of the URLs is that they're after "wiki/" and have no spaces. Then you don't have to worry about escaping parentheses, etc